# XCode 4.6 OpenGL|ES integrated performance tools with custom build script

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode4.6

I have a large iOS project with a complex custom build script written in Jam.
The app is compiled through a Run Script build phase.

When I run the app on a device from XCode the performance tray with the fps counter under the Debug Navigator doesn't show up.

For a simple XCode OpenGL|ES sample application the performance tray shows up fine.

Is there anything I can check/do to get the integrated OpenGL|ES performance tools to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it turns out is going to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme and in the Options tab changing OpenGL ES Frame Capture from Automatically Enabled to Enabled.